# Can I unlock a brand new user to SSH in without setting password?

Tags: server, ssh, login, users, sshd

I'm following these steps when setting up the user:

```
$ sudo useradd periscope -m -s /bin/false
$ sudo su -s /bin/bash periscope
$ mkdir ~/.ssh
$ # public key gets manually input here
$ cat - >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
$ chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
$ chmod go-w ~/ ~/.ssh
```

Now when I try to log into this user I'm faced with the following error in `/var/log/auth.log`:

```
Jun 13 18:50:21 ip-172-31-27-167 sshd[12811]: User periscope not allowed because account is locked
Jun 13 18:50:21 ip-172-31-27-167 sshd[12811]: input_userauth_request: invalid user periscope [preauth]
```

and `/etc/shadow` shows:

```
periscope:!:17331:0:99999:7:::
```

which according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passwd means that the user is locked from a password login (good) but could be authorized to log in with SSH, which is what I want. auth.log doesn't agree however.

The way I've fixed this before is by setting a random password for that user, ssh would work then. Doesn't feel like the right solution though, I'm not enabling (or maybe not, since it's disabled in `sshd`?) a login method I am not interested in.

Another option that folks suggested was to use `sudo passwd -u periscope` instead but then I get the following error:

```
passwd: unlocking the password would result in a passwordless account.
You should set a password with usermod -p to unlock the password of this account.
```

Is setting a password for a user, even though I never intend on using it, unavoidable?

Comment: Have you checked your SSH settings for your server? Also, It looks like you might be shooting yourself in the foot by setting the /bin/false as the shell... unless you are going to manually call the shell when sshing in.

Comment: @ben-NabiyDerush - what specific settings do you recommend I take a look into?

Comment: @ben-NabiyDerush regarding /bin/false this user will only be used for ssh forwarding as per https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/redshift-cluster-setup-private-ip.html

Comment: Ok. Well, I followed the same steps you used for creating the account etc, but mine worked (apart from /bin/false not allowing session to remain) I would look into /etc/ssh/sshd_config and make sure UsePAM is yes and PubKeyAuthentication is yes. That would be a start

Comment: IIRC `~/.ssh` must be mode `700` (i.e. `go-rwx`) - I think `go-w` is still too permissive

Comment: @ben-NabiyDerush I have `UsePAM` set to `no` as of today. Would you recommend that I change that setting? I'm not thoroughly familiar with the kind of effect that would have on SSH-based logins

Comment: Just to clarify, according to this post if I never do password-based logins, I should be disabling that setting: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1749340

Comment: You can have UsePAM as no then. Also, steeldriver is right, permissions on ~/.ssh folder should be 700. It is hard saying why mine works and yours doesn't without comparing the two. Have you tried a verbose connection to see what the issue is?

Comment: If you aren't going to make `sshd` available outside your machine, then `usermod -p '' LOGIN`. That unlocks the user, but doesn't set a password (see `passwd -S`). Or empty password is probably indistinguishable from no password.